# How to set different themes for button selector?

Tags: android, button, themes, selector

How can i set different styles for button selector according to current app theme?

Here is my button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="@color/color_theme1"/>
        </item>
 <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
 <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Comment: The obvious answer would be to use an actual theme color instead of `@color/color_theme1`, e.g. like `?colorPrimary`. This being said, this will only work with api 21 or above

Answer (score 3):

As your app theme color is in color_primary in color.xml. you can use that in your selector like this. But you have to create two drawables file one for default state and other for selected_state.

**button_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--selected/pressed/focused -->
<item       android:state_selected="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected"
            />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default"/>
 <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

**button_default.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<!--this is to give gradient effect -->
<gradient   android:angle="270"
               android:startColor="@color/gray"
               android:endColor="#@color/gray"
               />
<!-- this will make corners of button rounded -->
<corners    android:topLeftRadius="5dip"
               android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"
               android:topRightRadius="5dip"
               android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"/>

</shape>
```

**button_selected.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<!--this is to give gradient effect -->
<gradient   android:angle="270"
            android:startColor="@color/color_primary"
            android:endColor="#@color/color_primary"
            />
<!-- this wil make corners of button rounded -->
<corners    android:topLeftRadius="5dip"
               android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"
               android:topRightRadius="5dip"
               android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"/>

</shape>
```

you have to programmatically do the following as well, so that the button will stay selected.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.isSelected())
                {
                    v.setSelected(false);
                }
                else
                {
                     v.setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I just want to change the button pressed color according to the selected theme.

Comment: thanks, for your clarification, your actual question is something but you have mentioned about using styles in your question. edited your question.please approve.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic selector in your app so that you can assign colors according to your requirements.

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.focused));
states.addState(new int[] { },
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));
imageView.setImageDrawable(states);
```

Or

Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754067/dynamically-defining-and-using-selectors) can help you

Comment: Any XML alternatives?