# Imageview set color filter to gradient

Tags: android, imageview, gradient

I have a white image that I'd like to color with a gradient. Instead of generating a bunch of images each colored with a specific gradient, I'd like to do this in code (not xml).

To change an image's color, I use

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN);
```

And this works fine. But how can I apply a gradient color instead of a solid color? `LinearGradient` doesn't help, because setColorFilter can't be applied to `Shader` objects.

**EDIT**: This is the image I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

And this is what I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Are you using ImageView in xml to draw the image in the first place?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob no, I'm creating them dynamically in code.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have to get `Bitmap` of your `ImageView` and redraw same `Bitmap` with `Shader`

```
public void clickButton(View v){
    Bitmap myBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)myImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    Bitmap newBitmap = addGradient(myBitmap);
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), newBitmap));
}


public Bitmap addGradient(Bitmap originalBitmap) {
    int width = originalBitmap.getWidth();
    int height = originalBitmap.getHeight();
    Bitmap updatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(updatedBitmap);

    canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, 0xFFF0D252, 0xFFF07305, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

    return updatedBitmap;
}
```

**UPDATE 3**
I changed: colors of gradient, LinearGradient width = 0 and PorterDuffXfermode.
Here a good picture to understand  PorterDuffXfermode:
[image]

Comment: How can this be used with an imageview?

Comment: @Malfunction Is it useful for you ?

Comment: This doesn't work - the gradient is set up as a rect, not on the shape itself.

Comment: @Malfunction, your question is about a white image in ImageView not shape. What's your shape ? Do you have to detect a shape in your ImageView ?

Comment: Exactly, I have a white image that I want to color with gradient. What I'm getting is a gradient along the entirety of the imageView's width and height (its rect), not on the image itself.

Comment: @Malfunction, sorry I don't understand. Could you post an image of your screen with ImageView and surround your full ImageView and surround part where you want gradient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114876/discussion-between-laurenty-and-malfunction).

Comment: Perfect! Changing the PorterDuffXfermode did the trick. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: In API 29, I had to do `canvas.density = originalBitmap.density` for it to work correctly. I have no idea why.

Answer (score -4):

You could use a selector

main_header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/.    android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/main_header_selector"> 
</LinearLayout>
```

main_header_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/.     android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:endColor="#FF00FF00"
        android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

The same background can be applied to an ImageView.

To define and use selector dynamically, refer to this link :
[Dynamically defining and using selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754067/dynamically-defining-and-using-selectors)

Comment: This is for applying a background though. I need something that changes the image itself.

Answer (score -5):

Create a XML file , and place it in the drawable folder .

**gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#CCb1e7fa"
    android:centerColor="#B3ffffff"
    android:endColor="#CCb1e7fa"
    android:angle="180" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Next add this as a background to your image view

```
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/umageview1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
```