# Set ImageView Drawable to PaintDrawable - Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-drawable

I would like to set my ImageView to a SweepGradient.

Here's what I tried:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ImageView colorPicker = findViewById(R.id.color_picker);
    colorPicker.setImageDrawable(CreateColorPickerDrawable());

}

private PaintDrawable CreateColorPickerDrawable()
{
    int[] colors = {0xFFFF0000, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFF0000FF};
    PaintDrawable paintDrawable = new PaintDrawable();

    paintDrawable.setCornerRadius(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.corner_radius));

    SweepGradient sweepGradient = new SweepGradient(50, 50, colors, null);
    paintDrawable.getPaint().setShader(sweepGradient);

    return paintDrawable;
}
```

But no gradient appears.

I've also seen this: [Imageview set color filter to gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775675/imageview-set-color-filter-to-gradient)

But I'm thinking there's got to be a simpler solution than that (plus it requires a bitmap src and I just want my ImageView to be a rectangle w/ rounded corners [which can be done easily w/ the PaintDrawable]).

If anyone has any guidance/advice it would be much appreciated! Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being a derp. I just had to switch the ImageView to a normal View and then I could replace the background drawable to my paintDrawable.

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View colorPicker = findViewById(R.id.color_picker);
colorPicker.setBackground(CreateColorPickerDrawable());

}

private PaintDrawable CreateColorPickerDrawable() {
int[] colors = {0xFFFF0000, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFF0000FF};
PaintDrawable paintDrawable = new PaintDrawable();

paintDrawable.setCornerRadius(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.corner_radius));

SweepGradient sweepGradient = new SweepGradient(50, 50, colors, null);
paintDrawable.getPaint().setShader(sweepGradient);

return paintDrawable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a static solution, you can use a XML file in drawable.

XML (gradient_1.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#aa0000"
        android:centerColor="#00aa00"
        android:endColor="#0000aa"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Java

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewGradient);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gradient_1);
```

Comment: I would like it to be dynamic eventually, the hard-coded colors were just for testing. Sorry dude :/