# How to set dynamically gradient tint to imageView on Android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

In my application I want to set dynamically **gradient colors** to `imageView`.
I can set solid color with the following code:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.grayColor),
                         android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

But I want to set **gradient color instead of solid color**.

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imageview set color filter to gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775675/imageview-set-color-filter-to-gradient)

Comment: Does the duplicate question answer your question? If not, then post an expected output image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method after getting bitmap

```
public Bitmap setGradientBackground(Bitmap originalBitmap) {
        int width = originalBitmap.getWidth();
        int height = originalBitmap.getHeight();
        Bitmap updatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(updatedBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, 0xFFF0D252, 0xFFF07305, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

        return updatedBitmap;
    }
```