# How can I detect ScrollView is scrolling

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-scrollview

I know that this question have been asked before and i have gone through them but they didnt solve my problem.

I have ScrollView with one LinearLayout with imageview. And i have used ontouchListner to imageview to give them click effect like this

```
switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xCCCDDC39, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            view.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            view.invalidate();
            startActivity(view.getId());
            break;
}
```

But the problem is whenever i scroll ontouchlistner is called of imageview and image gets clicked .I dont want this whenever i am scrolling , Because this does not allow me to scroll. Please help

Comment: Try using `onClickListener` instead of touch listener to handle click events & `selector` to change the color of the view on click.

Comment: i tried that , It does not give the effect i want . for example when the user tap and hold on icon it should be green until user leave the icon . This effect cannot be achieved from onClickListner

Comment: Did you use `selector` also? You can dynamically set two images for the pressed and normal state programmatically. Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754067/dynamically-defining-and-using-selectors

Comment: I know selector . Reason i didnt used it that because i have around 40 images if i will use selector then i have to used double images 80 and it can increase app size i think

Comment: and when i used selector to draw some color on it . it draw green color all over image making unvisible all can i see is green color

Comment: No need to use another set of 40 images for selected image. You can create the selector dynamically & apply color filter. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, You can use `onClickListener` and `selector` to achieve this. Also you don't have to keep duplicate set of images for the selected state. You can create the selector dynamically like this

```
        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your image);
        drawable.setColorFilter(0xCCCDDC39, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, drawable);
        yourView.setBackground(states);
```

Comment: I have to do this for all images

Comment: You just have to write this code at one place right? You are already setting background image to the view. Just add this state_pressed state along with it.

Comment: which image is R.drawable.your Image?

Comment: The image which you are setting as background to view

Answer (score 0):

> a sure short asnwer

```
scroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {


                    int x = scrollY - oldScrollY;
                    if (x > 0) {
                        //scroll up
                    } else if (x < 0) {
                        //scroll down
                    } else {

                    }

        }
    });
```